# oAuth 1/2 library for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm looking for most popular oAuth 1/2 library for Ruby. I thought it was signet, but it turned out that its github page has been removed.

Your thoughts?

Comment: maybe omniauth if easy authentication with numerous popular sites is what you are after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) to find the most popular option. It turns out that it's [intridea's omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth). If you want to turn your app into OAuth provider [doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper) may be useful.